# Extract key value pairs from json object and group them - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json, angular

Here is my fiddle : [DEMO1](http://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/bs32v01w/11/)

The following function extracts the keys and values and stores it in a new array. This works right for objects(json2 and json3) and not when there is an array of objects (json1)

Is there a way to group a set of key value pairs into an object and then push that object into the array?
    `Desired output : [{"timestamp":1540457640,"speed":"70"},{"timestamp":1541383353,"speed":"80"},{"timestamp":1541383353,"speed":"70"},{"timestamp":1542256083,"speed":"70"}]`

```
function iterate(obj) {
  for (var property in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      if (typeof obj[property] == "object") {
        iterate(obj[property]);
        if (isNaN(Number(property))) {
          if ((Array.isArray(obj[property])) && (typeof obj[property][0] != "object")) {
            simpleArrayKeys[property] = obj[property];
          }
        }
      } else {
        if (isNaN(Number(property))) {
          simpleArrayKeys[property] = obj[property];
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The built-in functions Object.keys(), Object.values() and Object.entries() do this apart from the nesting. So using those in combination with .reduce() , .flatten() and .map() lets you create any transformation you want.

Comment: @Shilly: This variant, https://jsfiddle.net/inchrvndr/gyujmokk/139/ with further transformation too might not work, if key names are same within different child objects (i.e, owner and driver objects have the same key names)

Answer (score 0):

You can map the data array like so:

```
var output = json1.data.allStreamingData.map(d => {
  return {
    "timestamp": d.timestamp,
    "speed": d.streamData.speed
  }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fghjtsnm/

Comment: The input json object could be anything, it is not timestamp/speed always to use the suggested format of return.

Comment: Anything? So you want to take any level of nesting and promote those keys/values up to the top level object? How could you ensure there wouldn't be duplicate keys? Is there some level of structure to the data?

Comment: Yes, the assumptions are that, there wont be any duplicate key and no arrays inside the nested structure, there can be objects.